# Why my node_modules folder is excluded in my phpStorm?

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

[Hello guys! every time i run the `npm install`command, it creates the node_modules folder, but the folder is excluded! Also i have some warnings as you can see, but i think that npm install is done successfully.
the Warnings that i get are the following:

**npm WARN** deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

**npm WARN** deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue

**npm WARN** deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.

**npm WARN** prefer global marked@0.3.6 should be installed with -g

**npm WARN** prefer global node-gyp@3.4.0 should be installed with -g

**npm WARN** optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):

**npm WARN** notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

The first 3 warnings are from the gulp depentency. and the last 2 i can pass them by, if i type the following code in the package.json:

```
*"optionalDependencies": {

          "fsevents": "*"

},*
```

and then type into the terminal the command `npm install --no-optional`.
But i can't understand why my node_modules folder is excluded and PhpStorm(2016.2.2) doesn't allow me to unexcluded it.
Thank you!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4qAR.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "excluded"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe they're not considered source files, as the contents of the `node_modules` folder are imported dependencies.

Having that folder excluded helps to to speed up searching in your project; as PhpStorm doesn't need to search through all the external modules.

This is what the [JetBrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html) has to say:

> Excluded folders are not involved in indexing and therefore they are ignored while searching, parsing, watching etc.,

So there's nothing wrong with having a folder marked as 'excluded'.

However, should you want to un-exclude the node_modules folder, have a look at [this thread on JetBrains support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/208376385-How-to-unexclude-node-modules-in-2016-2-2-). This thread was started by someone with the same problem. One of the suggestions there:

> Please open "Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries" and locate "/lib/node_modules" library. Is it enabled? If no, just enable it. Will it bring expected code completion and navigation in your main application for modules imported from `lib/node_modules`?

Comment: I unchecked it, but still i can't un-exclude it!
My friend what does this excluded "node_modules" folder mean for my project? (cause i'm new in this stuff)
Does it mean that something is going wrong? Or something is not working properly? 
Thank you again!

Comment: @tsam nope, nothing's wrong! I've updated my answer with an explanation of an excluded folder.

Comment: thank you for your help! i though it was something like an error, but as you said it's not.